# Does SharePoint online support MS Infopath?

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, office-365

Does SharePoint online support MS Info path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infopath supported on the SharePoint Online until new announcement .Infopath Service 2013 is latest release of it is configured in the SharePoint online.  You have to make sure you are on the right plan to use the Infopath service [check this comparison.](http://Office%20365%20Enterprise%20E3%20Office%20365%20Enterprise%20E5)

Check this: [Configure InfoPath Forms Services](http://Configure%20InfoPath%20Forms%20Services)

[InfoPath Forms Services differences between SharePoint Online (DvNext/MT) and SharePoint On-Premises](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4017854/infopath-forms-services-differences-between-sharepoint-online-dvnext-m)